# Twitter bootstrap : collapsible element in collapsible element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, collapsable

Disclaimers first :
1) First question ever, I hope I'm doing this right, apologies if it's not the case.
2) English is not my native language, so sorry for any mistakes.
3) Made a search and couldn't find an answer.

Trying to explain in words will mean many words while a bootply can say it all :

http://www.bootply.com/EBIMFQ5jEC

Basically, what I want is almost working except for this : I would like that clicking on "title 3" for instance (after you've clicked on "title 1" or "title 2") hides the "first/second column(s)" so that the "third column" is the only one shown (and vice-versa of course). I hope this is clear.

I tried a few things with data-parent (such as this: http://www.bootply.com/pgoT2IPG8D which has `data-parent="#collapse1"` added for the first three buttons) but couldn't achieve anything...

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: you're going to have to include what you have tried, so that we can help you troubleshoot it...

Comment: Basically, this : http://www.bootply.com/pgoT2IPG8D but I'm not quite sure I understand how data-parent works to be honest...

Comment: is it the same as what you pasted in the question?

Comment: No, there is `data-parent="#collapse1"` added for the first three buttons :)

Comment: please edit your original question annotating it as an "edit", and providing that explanation.

Comment: It's done ! Any idea on how to make this work ?

Comment: bootstrap collapse is plugin dependant: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get what this means...? :)

Comment: `Requires JavaScript plugin (...) The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.`

Comment: Well I think it is included, isn't it ? The collapsing in itself works fine, it's just that I can't get it to have the behaviour I want.

Comment: do you always want to only show one column at a time?

Comment: Well, two columns actually : the "title" column, and only one of the three possible "subtitle" columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want you will indeed have to set the `data-parent', but also notice that this also require a '.panel' class. From the docs:

> If a selector is provided, then all collapsible elements under the
>   specified parent will be closed when this collapsible item is shown.
>   (similar to traditional accordion behavior - this is dependent on the
>   panel class)

demo: http://www.bootply.com/qhs4dQbFZK

So you should wrap you collapsible item in a `.panel` class (or change the plugin). See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15341

Then a collapsible item will look that shown below:

```
<div class="panel">        
    <div class="col-md-2 collapse" id="collapse1">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block" data-toggle="buttons">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="">First subtitle column</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1-1"><input type="radio" name="subtitle" id="st11">Subtitle 1-1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1-2"><input type="radio" name="subtitle" id="st12">Subtitle 1-2</button>       
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1-3"><input type="radio" name="subtitle" id="st13">Subtitle 1-3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your button should get a `data-parent` attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menurow" href="#collapse1"><input type="radio" name="title" id="title1">Title 1</button>
```

And your items should be wrapped inside the id set before (`#menurow`):

```
<div class="row" id="menurow"></div>
```

Notice that the `.panel` class also set some style rules, which should be overrules (undo) for your situation, for instance: `.panel {margin-bottom: 0;}`

Comment: I'll look into this and try to figure out what's going on and I'll get back to you, but it seems to be exactly what I need, thank you very much !

Is the `.panel` class the cause of each column being a small bit lower than the previous one ?)

Comment: Possible is wrapping the `.panel` classes inside `.container .row` not the best idea? Why do you it in the grid? An alternative can be found at http://www.bootply.com/DY3AcNi7Ru. Notice that this requires some more changes for the `.panel` class. You also should find a solution for the smaller grids (mobile view)